# SQL query of sales by customer over multiple years for top 50 customers in one year

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nested

I have a query in SQL server that successfully returns the top 50 customers for a given year by sales. I want to expand it to return their sales for the additional years when they may or may not be in the top 50.

```
SELECT TOP 50 CU.CustomerName, SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis) AS '2011'
FROM ARTransaction AS ART, Customer AS CU
WHERE ART.CustomerN = CU.CustomerN AND ART.PostingDate BETWEEN '2010-12-31' AND '2012-01-01'
GROUP By CU.CustomerName
ORDER BY SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis) DESC
```

I tried adding nested SELECT statements but they return strange results and I'm not sure why (might not ever work, but the results have me flabbergasted anyway). When included the values of every row is changed and customers are duplicated.

```
(SELECT SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis)
WHERE ART.PostingDate BETWEEN '2011-12-31' AND '2013-01-01') AS '2012'
```

I tried to put a TOP statement in a nested SELECT in HAVING but that tells me

"Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1

Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

```
SELECT CU.CustomerName, SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis) AS '2011'
FROM ARTransaction AS ART 
JOIN Customer AS CU ON ART.CustomerN = CU.CustomerN
GROUP BY CU.CustomerNAme
HAVING CU.CustomerNAme IN 
        (SELECT TOP 50 CU.CustomerName
        FROM ARTransaction
        JOIN Customer ON ARTransaction.CustomerN = Customer.CustomerN
        WHERE ARTransaction.SalesAnalysis BETWEEN '2010-12-31' AND '2012-01-01'
    GROUP BY Customer.CustomerN
    ORDER BY SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis) DESC)
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. I'll add that to the body.

Comment: Just a quick note on using `between`... it is inclusive of the dates specified so in your first query you are getting all of 2011 plus the 31 dec 2010 and 1 jan 2012.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the `between`. That explains some of the weird results I've gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the top 50 sales for customers based on 2011 data - and want to see all years data for those top 50 from 2011, regardless of those customers being in the top 50 for other years.

Try this, it might need to be tweaked a bit as I don't know the schema, but if I understand the question correctly, this should do the trick.

```
    WITH Top50 AS (
    SELECT TOP 50 
           CU.CustomerN
          ,SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis) AS SalesTotal
      FROM 
           ARTransaction art
     INNER JOIN
           Customer cu
        ON cu.CustomerN = art.CustomerN
     WHERE 
           ART.PostingDate BETWEEN CAST('2011-01-01' AS DATETIME) 
       AND CAST('2011-12-31' AS DATETIME)
     GROUP BY 
           CU.CustomerN
     ORDER BY 
           SUM(ART.SalesAnalysis) DESC)

    SELECT 
           c.CustomerName
          ,SUM(a.SalesAnalysis) AS TotalSales
          ,YEAR(a.PostingDate) AS PostingDateYear
      FROM
           ARTransaction a
     INNER JOIN
           Customer c
        ON c.CustomerN = a.CustomerN
     INNER JOIN
           Top50 t
        ON t.CustomerN = a.CustomerN
     GROUP BY 
           c.CustomerName
          ,YEAR(a.PostingDate)
     ORDER BY
           PostingDateYear
```

Comment: A little tweaking got this to work fine, thank you. I'm going to need to learn more about WITH because it seems to be very helpful.

Comment: Glad that helped!  To read more about CTE's, go here [Common table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  They are helpful in many cases, but as always with everything, they may not be the right fit all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like below... you will be looking at the all the data for all the years you want to look at and then just getting the top 50 for the 2011 year

```
SELECT TOP 50 
    CU.CustomerName, 
    SUM(case when year(ART.PostingDate) = 2011 -- or you could use case when ART.PostingDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
        then ART.SalesAnalysis
        else 0 end) AS 2011, 
    SUM(case when year(ART.PostingDate) = 2012
        then ART.SalesAnalysis
        else 0 end) AS 2012
FROM 
    ARTransaction ART, 
    inner join Customer CU
        on ART.CustomerN = CU.CustomerN
WHERE ART.PostingDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01 AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP By CU.CustomerName
ORDER BY  
    SUM(case when year(ART.PostingDate) = 2011
        then ART.SalesAnalysis
        else 0 end)  DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. Had to fix an extra comma or two so wasn't sure.